Play Console Warning: Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version or face crash in android 14
Update com.google.android.play
com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.10.3:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.
Java
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (appupdateType.equals("critical") && !Objects.equals(myAppVersion, playStoreVersion)) {
            appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {

                    if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS)) {
                        // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                        try {
                            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                    appUpdateInfo,
                                    IMMEDIATE,
                                    Splash.this,
                                    MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.e("error on resume", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                        }
                    }
                    if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UNKNOWN)) {
                        popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate();
                        appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (appupdateType.equals("flexible") && !Objects.equals(myAppVersion, playStoreVersion)) {
            appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                    if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UNKNOWN)) {
                        popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate();
                        appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

i have checked the developer.google.android and found

implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1',com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2

but i am facing error after update dependency
here is sample code where i am facing error
how to replace code or what to use in replace of  AppUpdateManager, com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task appUpdateInfoTask;

I think you missed the part in the docs where you have change the imports as well

Update any existing import statements of Task objects from import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.; to import com.google.android.gms.tasks.;

So, as far as your question is concerned, what you do is
com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task appUpdateInfoTask

will be replaced with
com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task appUpdateInfoTask

Hope this helps!

not working solution , i have tried replace core task dependency with gms but it still showing error because I have to import play core
my clear concern is that how to I upload to latest play code dependency ,currently I am using implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

Please read my answer here and upvote so that people facing similar queries like you don't miss it if it helps

In my case, The issue is little different. I have not used the com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library in my project. But Play Store show the error message as

Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an
Android 14 compatible version! Your current
com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a
backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder,
from August 31, 2024, Google Play requires all new app releases to
target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to
avoid app crashes.

I spend 4 hours time to find the issue but tired. Finally, I have a hunch,
I went to File -> Project Structure
On Project Structure screen, I have found the library used in other libraries.
Example: (for example I am showing a library, but the finding & solution applicable to any other library)
Just consider to find the usage of "androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0". At build.gradle or build.gradle.kts file, I have not used this library.
But on Project Structure screen:

The androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0 library used inside the com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0 library.
Same format I followed for com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library also. So what are other core libraries used com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3, I removed those libraries and updated relevant new library.
So first and foremost thing is find the usage of the library.
